# Temporarily disable optimization of const-qualified variables? (during debugging)

Tags: c++, optimization, constants

I have a complex framework (sadly I can't re-write it, hence my question) that I wrote for my own use, and it involves heavy use of float arrays.

Those float arrays are passed as `const float*` between many functions and objects.

However, I need to perform a special debugging-procedure ("gradient-checking" for Neural nets) in specific areas of my code. It allows me to see if manual perturbation of my array-entries will lead to expected value change later, elsewhere. If not, then I made mistake in intermediate formulas.

I wrote a tool that acceps a const array and perturbs some of its values.

As a result, during this temporary debugging procedure I cast those `const float*` to `float*` using reinterpret cast. This is horrible and leads to undefined behavior. I modify values inside const arrays and pray it doesn't break when running this debugging version (it doesn't half of the time).

**Question:**

Is it possible to temporarily prevent compiler from optimizing code everythwere where it sees `const float*` just to give me chance to debug my code, via my checking-tool?

In other words, so I can safely cast `const float*` to `float*` for the time-being.

Is there some #define that I could use in my code, or compiler flag for Visual Studio?

I am using c++ 17 and Visual Studio

---

**Edit after accepting the answer**

This time the issue was not in the cast, but in something overwriting memory outside the array. By using Memory Watch breakpoint in Visual studio, and the callstack, I was able to track-down the place where it was occurring

Comment: `#define const` ;)

Comment: @jtbandes That will likely break many things, in particular when there are const and non-const overloads of member functions in a class.

Comment: If original array is really `const`, and so disallows the `const_cast`, copying might still be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cast those const float* to float* using reinterpret cast. This is
>   horrible and leads to undefined behavior.

Casting away a const qualifier does not, in itself, lead to undefined behavior. You can use a `const_cast<float*>` to remove the const qualifier **if you know the pointed to object is non-const**. You must declare the array itself it have non-const storage.

> Is it possible to temporarily prevent compiler from optimizing code
>   everythwere where it sees const float* just to give me chance to debug
>   my code, via my checking-tool?

`const` is not an optimization feature, it's a type safety feature. If your compiler implicitly converts `const float*` to `float*`, it's not a compliant C++ compiler.

> Is there some #define that I could use in my code, or compiler flag
>   for Visual Studio?

If you need to compile this code for both cases, you can use a `typedef` to achieve this:

```
typedef float *flt_ptr;
//or
typedef const float *flt_ptr;
```

You must still declare the storage on your array correctly (non-const when using the first typedef).

Many people consider `typedef` pointers to be unreadable and error-prone (you have to remember not to use the `*` in all your pointers now). You are probably best using a limited number of `const_cast`'s in key locations and ensuring that the original array is non-const.

Comment: Many other people consider non-typedef pointers to be unreadable and error-prone. Why not typedef only type itself? like `using flt = float const;`